# Google Play Store download stops to a certain percentage on large programs

Tags: google-play-store, download-manager

Hey fellow Android Enthusiasts,

I have encountered a very weird problem which I hope you could help. When I download a large apps from Google Play Store, it always pauses at a certain percentage, for example:

1. Angry Bird 2 (about 120 MB of download size), the download always stopped at 61%.
2. Need for Speed No Limits (About 787 MB of download size), the download always stopped at 97%.

When I say stop, basically the Download Manager would suddenly disappear and then the Download bar in Google Play Store would just be “stuck” at that percentage (data traffic speed also dropped from a few M/s to a few k/s before hitting 0). I have tried downloading via mobile data or Wi-Fi and both still result the same.

I thought it was because my phones are running out of storage space, however my internal storage has 24.58 GB free and SD card has 4.55 GB free, either of which is way larger than the installation size of the two games listed above. It is also weird that the downloader stopped at the higher percentage in N4S game than AB2 game since N4S has much larger download size than AB2.

I have tried canceling the download and re-downloading and it stuck at the exactly same percentage. I have also tried cleaning the cache (/Cache/Download and delete everything in there) and even tried deleting the entire Google Play Store app and reinstalling it, and the exactly same thing happenned. I have also switched to different Wi-Fi network and switched between Wi-Fi and Mobile data.

My Google Play Store is the highest version I can find on Apkmirror (version 7.9.52.Q-all[0][PR]156316931) and I have given the permission to Storage and my Location. Phone is Huawei P9 Plus (VIE-AL10) and currently on Build Number B356 (Android 7.0 with Kernel version 4.1.18-gf6402d0).

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest getting APK files from your favorite APK website for the apps in question. Also, try updating Google Play from the Google Play store, NOT Apkmirror. 
Not to mention the obvious stuff such as force restarting google play services, or restarting your phone.
You could also just give it a while. My phone does something similar where it will get stuck at 100% and will take a while to go to installing. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks but I don't think I can find Google Play from Google Play Store...may be I am missing something...

Comment: You can go to **Play Store->Settings**. Then click on **Play Store version** one or two times. Then, if any update is available, it will be automatically downloaded and installed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not close or cancel it. After some time it will already start downloading . I also got struck many time while downloading a game but my mistake was that when it downloading stops i always cancel the download. But  for first time i didn't do anything for 5-10 minutes after which it already start downloading and download manager again appears ..I was downloading Call of duty mobile unreleased

Answer (score -1):

i too had face this problem with my home WiFi. for resolving this issue you should reset your home WiFi settins or your

Comment: Can you give the steps to do that?