# Percentage reach a certain number then stop when trying to download an app from Play Store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation

When I try downloading an app on Play Store (even if it doesn't take up a big space), it would reach a certain percentage and then just stop. I tried waiting for a bit however; when I do, I get a weird message that tells me that I can't install the app.

I've never had this issue before. I have plenty of storage in my phone; I have the latest update on both my phone and Play Store; my WiFi is relatively good and usually installing apps wouldn't take seconds. I had tried restarting my phone; clearing Cache and doing a bunch of recommended stuff, but when I try to install the same app, guess what? It stops at the same percentage.

Please help me fix this problem. I don't want to abandon my account or remove data from my phone (OPPO Reno5 5G).

Comment: I once had this problem. I went to the website/review of where this app was mentioned (using mobile browser) and it had a link to the app. Clicking that took me to Play Store and it installed fine. Before doing all this I may have rebooted too, don't recollect

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have a few questions about a similar issue: [Google Play Store download stops to a certain percentage on large programs](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/176526/44325), [Why can't I install anything since Google Play Store downloads don't reach 100%?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242689/44325).